# Flux / Fluxible: Updating routes based on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-router

What is the most concise way to trigger route changes based on a change to a state store, using Fluxible and react router?

An example component might take some user input and call an Action on a click event (shortened for brevity)

```
class NameInput extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = props.state;
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick (event) {
        this.context.executeAction(setName, {name:'Some User Value'});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Set Name" onClick={this.handleClick} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

The `handleClick` method executes an Action which can update a Store with our new value.

But what if I *also* want this to trigger a navigation after the Store is updated? I *could* add the `router` context type and directly call the transition method after executing the Action:

```
this.context.executeAction(setName, {name:'Some User Value'});
this.context.router.transitionTo('some-route');
```

But this assumes that the `setName` Action is synchronous. Is this conceptually safe, on the assumption that the new route will re-render once the Action is completed and the Store is updated?

Alternatively, should the original Component listen for Store Changes and start the route transition based on some assessment of the store state?

Using the Fluxible, `connectToStores` implementation, I can listen for discreet changes to Store state:

```
NameInput = connectToStores(NameInput, [SomeStore], function (stores, props) {
    return {
        name: stores.SomeStore.getState().name
    }
});
```

How a could a Store listener of this type be used to initiate a Route change?

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed in my own application that for these kinds of flows it's usually safer to let actions do all the hard work. Annoying thing here is that the router isn't accessible from actions.

So, this is what I'd do:

Create a meta-action that does both: `setNameAndNavigate`. As payload you use something like this:

```
{
   name: 'Value',
   destination: {to: 'some-route', params: []},
   router: this.context.router
}
```

Then, in your action, do the navigating when the setName completes.

It's not ideal, especially the passing of the Router to the action. There's probably some way to attach the Router to the action context, but that's not as simple as I had hoped. This is probably a good starting point though.

---

Extra reading:

Why do everything in actions? It's risky to execute actions in components in response to store changes. Since Fluxible 0.4 you can no longer let actions dispatch *inside* another dispatch. This happens a lot faster than you think, for example, executing an action in response to a change in a store, without delaying it with `setImmediate` or `setTimeout`, will kill your application since store changes happen synchronously during a dispatch.

Inside actions however, you can easily execute actions and dispatches, and wait for them to complete before executing the next one.

The end result of working this way is that most of your application logic has moved to actions, and your components turn into simple views that set-and-forget actions **only** in response to user interactions (clicks/scrolling/hover/..., as long as it's not in response to a store change).

Comment: Thanks, initiating the navigation from inside the action was what I'd planned originally, but I assumed there must be a reason that the router isn't available on the actionContext.

Passing it in the payload seems OK as long as the action remains stateless and doesn't hold on to it. Going to play around with this and see what I come up with. Thanks.

Comment: It's a downside of using fluxibleContexts. Following Flux guidelines, the router should be used read-only in components, and actions that have effects on the router should only be available from within actions.

A navigate is a 'state change'. Without React-Router, this would be a change to the RouteStore/ApplicationStore. By doing this from inside a component, you violate Flux. Passing the Router to the action is a workaround, but ultimately 'better'.

Comment: Agree that calling it directly from the component is not the way to go. Looks like the best answer might be to create a plugin similar to https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible-plugin-routr/blob/master/docs/fluxible-plugin-routr.md but using react-router

Answer (score 2):

The Best way is to create a new action as @ambroos suggested,
`setNameAndNavigate`. For navigation though, use the `navigateAction`
https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/packages/fluxible-router/lib/navigateAction.js, you would only have to give the url as argument.
Something like this,

```
import async from 'async';
import setName from 'some/path/setName'; 

export default function setNameAndNavigate(context, params, done) {
   async.waterfall([
      callback => {
          setName(context, params, callback);
      },
      (callback) => {
          navigate(context, {
             url: '/someNewUrl',
          }, callback);
       }
   ], done);    
}
```

let your actions be the main workers as much as possible.